# Column renaming python | col1-keep, col2-headers, col3-values

Tags: python, knime

I try to find a way how to do following in Knime

I have a file like

```
|    Column      |
|----------------|
|a.type_1 = "aaa"|
|a.type_2 = "bbb"|
|a.type_3 = "ccc"|
|b.type_1 = "ddd"|
|b.type_2 = "bbb"|
|b.type_3 = "eee"|
|----------------|
```

By splitting I have reached

```
|Name|  Type  | Description|
|--------------------------|
|a   | type_1 | "aaa"      |
|a   | type_2 | "bbb"      |
|a   | type_3 | "ccc"      |
|b   | type_1 | "ddd"      |
|b   | type_2 | "bbb"      |
|b   | type_3 | "eee"      |
|--------------------------|
```

But in the end I want to have a table like

```
|Name| type_1 | type_2 | type_3 |
|-------------------------------|
|a   | "aaa"  |  "bbb" | "ccc"  |
|b   | "ddd"  | "bbb"  | "eee"  |
|-------------------------------|
```

Can you please give a tip how to do that? It would be also very helpful in case you share how to do that in python.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to manipulate text data. The "columns" aren't a data structure. Right? If so, I would load the "row" data in the second table as a dictionary of dictionaries (where each dictionary has keys of 'Name', 'Type' and 'Description'). Then I would loop and create a new dictionary based on the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a simple dictionary of your data. It prints both table formats: 1) with Name/Type/Description columns, then 2) with Name/type_1/type_2/type_3 columns. I didn't bother with table headers and footers. You can add that. :-)

```
row_dict = { 
        'row1': { 'Name':'a', 'Type':'type_1', 'Description':'aaa'},
        'row2': { 'Name':'a', 'Type':'type_2', 'Description':'bbb'},
        'row3': { 'Name':'a', 'Type':'type_3', 'Description':'ccc'},
        'row4': { 'Name':'b', 'Type':'type_1', 'Description':'ddd'},
        'row5': { 'Name':'b', 'Type':'type_2', 'Description':'bbb'},
        'row6': { 'Name':'b', 'Type':'type_3', 'Description':'eee'}  
            }

for row, data in row_dict.items():
    print(f"| {data['Name']} | {data['Type']} | {data['Description']} |")
print()    
    
new_dict = {}  # key: Name; Value dictionary of dictionaries of type
for row, data in row_dict.items():
    rname = data['Name']
    rtype = data['Type'] 
    rdesc = data['Description']
    if data['Name'] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[rname] = {rtype:rdesc}
    else:
        new_dict[rname].update({rtype:rdesc})
        
for row, data in new_dict.items():  
        #pr_str = f"| {row} | "
        pr_str = ''.join([f' {d} |' for d in data.values()])
        print('| ' + row + ' | ' + pr_str)
```

Output:

```
| a | type_1 | aaa |
| a | type_2 | bbb |
| a | type_3 | ccc |
| b | type_1 | ddd |
| b | type_2 | bbb |
| b | type_3 | eee |


| a |  aaa | bbb | ccc |
| b |  ddd | bbb | eee |
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a KNIME node for such table transformation (pivot):

https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.base.node.preproc.pivot.Pivot2NodeFactory

Pivot is also supported by pandas data frames:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html